# Error 7302 SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I work with SQL Server 2012 and  i have the next query:

```
CREATE TABLE Doc_tmp
    ( 
        DocGroupCode VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
        DocGroupText VARCHAR(255)  NULL
    )


insert into Doc_tmp (DocGroupCode, DocGroupText)
            select DocGroupCode, DocGroupText from openrowset('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\DocGroup.xls;', 'SELECT DocGroupCode, DocGroupText FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

When I run it I get the following

> Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"

What can I do? I tried some solutions but nothing.

Comment: Sounds like the driver is missing. Does the host that SQL is sat on have Excel installed?

Comment: Is `D:\DocGroup.xls` a path on the server or your machine?

Comment: I must specify that Excel Version is 2013 but i converted .xlsx file into .xls file.

Comment: The path of server are on the C:\

Comment: How did you convert .xlsx to xls. Just by changing extension OR proper save as .xls option?

Comment: I save as .xls option